# AngularJS: Unit testing state changes with resolve functions

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am fairly new to testing in AngularJS and am trying to write tests for a $stateProvider I have configured in this way:

```
angular.module("app.routing.config", []).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state("home", {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "app/modules/home/page/home_page.html",
    controller: "HomePageController",
    resolve: {
      setPageTitle: function($rootScope) {
        return $rootScope.pageTitle = "Home";
      }
    }
  }).state("somethingelse", {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "app/modules/home/page/somethingelse.html",
    controller: "SomeThingElseController",
    resolve: {
      setPageTitle: function($rootScope) {
        return $rootScope.pageTitle = "Some Thing Else";
      }
    }
  });
  return $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

I have already got a simple test written for checking the states translate to the correct pages, for example:

```
describe('State Change: home', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      $httpBackend.expectGET('app/modules/home/page/home_page.html').respond({});
      $templateCache.put(null, 'app/modules/home/page/home_page.html');
    });
    it('should go to the home state', function() {
      $location.url('home');
      $rootScope.$digest();
      $httpBackend.flush();
      expect($state.href('home')).toEqual('#/');
      expect($rootScope.pageTitle).toEqual('Home');
    });
  });
```

But I am stuck with how I would test the resolve setPageTitle function in my state config blocks. I think all I want right now is to be sure that the function got called (Spies?). I am just stuck on what to do next, can anyone give me any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when dealing with resolve functions, there are 2 essential things that you're trying to test: the injection of the code or their execution.

Execution: Your current example has been tested correctly, as you have resolved your route, and the title has been effectively updated by using:

```
expect($rootScope.pageTitle).toEqual('Home');
```

Injection: In the case where you're providing some extra features or functionality, the use case changes in that you're going to want to test how the controller uses the function. In that scenario you'll want to inject the code using the $controller function to test how the $controller leverages and uses the code

```
var mockFunction = function(aValue){.....}
var testedController = $controller('HomePageController', { ..., setPageTitle: mockFunction .....});
```

Comment: OK I got you, I saw some injection examples earlier when digging around with testing functionality in controllers and wondered if I needed to do the same. Thanks!